# Why Graphql cannot get the args by using variable but worked when using static var

Tags: laravel-5, graphql, laravel-5.7, graphql-php

My mutation scheme:

```
mutation edit($id: Int!) {
  user_edit(id:$id) {
    user_name
  }
}
```

query variable is follow

```
{
  "id": 1
}
```

I use this with laravel-graphql. Here is my definition of `user_edit`

```
class UserEdit extends Mutation
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'UserEdit',
        'description' => 'A mutation'
    ];

    public function type()
    {
        return GraphQL::type('UserInfo');
    }

    public function args()
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'type' => Type::int(),
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $info)
    {
        var_dump($args);exit;
        $data = User::find($args['id']);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

I use my query string to request the graphql server, then server return my error

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$edit1\" of required type \"Int!\" was not provided.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

l tried a lot things and read the document on github [https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql#creating-a-mutation][1]

and read the document of graphql's website ,and change my args definition style in many ways, but all failed, ***and Strange is*** l can get args but use ***static variable*** like follow

```
mutation edit{
      user_edit(id:1) {
        user_name
      }
    }
```

and then it worked! l tried to goole but get nothing about this. l think l really need some help

Comment: Please post the request you are making. You could also just try making a POST request instead -- while GET requests are technically supported, POST requests are used by convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is because of lower version, if you install laravel-graphql version with '~1.0.0',
go to modify `config/graphql.php`

```
// The name of the input that contain variables when you query the endpoint.
// Some library use "variables", you can change it here. "params" will stay
// the default for now but will be changed to "variables" in the next major
// release.

'variables_input_name' => 'variables', // modify here from 'params' to 'variables'
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the docs vs your code, seems in your `args` method, you needs to specify the arg name, like so:

```
public function args()
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'type' => Type::int(),
                'name' => 'id'
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Ref: https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql#creating-a-query

Hope this help!

Regards

Comment: l tried, it still told me, `Variable \"$id\" of required type \"Int!\" was not provided.`

Comment: How your request looks like?

Comment: l found the reason, that because My laravel-graphql version is too low, It's readme told me to install with ~1.0.0, but latest version is v1.1.0. Then, in my version, in the config file `config/graphql.php` has a config: `'variables_input_name' => 'params'`, and currectly config is `'variables_input_name' => 'variables',`